# Returning precise vector components in js canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, trigonometry

I have been wrestling with rendering an animation that fires a projectile accurately from an "enemy" node to a "player" node in a 2D 11:11 grid (0:0 = top-left) in JS/Canvas.  [After a lot of reading up](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-find-vector-components.html) I've managed to get the shots close, but not quite bang on.  I think my velocity function is a little out but I really don't know why.  This is the trigonometric function:

```
this.getVelocityComponents = function(speed){
// loc (location of enemy actor) = array(2) [X_coord, Y_coord]
// des (destination (ie. player in this instance)) = array(2) [X_coord, Y_coord]
var i, sum, hyp, output = [], dis = [];
var higher = false;
for (i in loc) {      
  sum = 0;
  if (loc[i] > des[i])
    sum = loc[i] - des[i];        
  if (loc[i] < des[i]) 
    sum = des[i] - loc[i];
  dis.push(sum);
}    
hyp = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dis[X], 2) + Math.pow(dis[Y], 2));
if (dis[X] > dis[Y]) {
  output[X] = (speed *  Math.cos(dis[X]/hyp))        
  output[Y] = (speed *  Math.sin(dis[Y]/hyp))        
} else if (dis[X] < dis[Y]) {
  output[X] = (speed *  Math.cos(dis[Y]/hyp))              
  output[Y] = (speed *  Math.sin(dis[X]/hyp))        
}
return output;
```

}

and this is the instruction that tells the X and the Y of the projectile frame to advance:

```
          var distance = [];
      for (i in loc) {      
        var sum = 0;
        if (loc[i] > des[i])
          sum = loc[i] - des[i];        
        if (loc[i] < des[i]) 
          sum = des[i] - loc[i];
        distance.push(sum);
      }  

      if (distance[X] > distance[Y]) {
        frm[X] += (loc[X] < des[X]) ? v[X] : -v[X];
        frm[Y] += (loc[Y] < des[Y]) ? v[Y] : -v[Y];
      } else {
        frm[Y] += (loc[Y] < des[Y]) ? v[X] : -v[X];
        frm[X] += (loc[X] < des[X]) ? v[Y] : -v[Y]; 
      }
```

Below is a screenshot.  Blue is player, pink enemy and the yellow circles are projectiles

[image: screenshot1]

as you can see, it's almost on the mark.

Have I done something wrong? what do I need to do?

Comment: It might help if you would actually ask a question.

Comment: As you requested, I have "asked a question". Bear in mind that the issue was implicit within what i had written: "fires a projectile accurately from an 'enemy'" ... "as you can see, it's almost on the mark." [but not precise, ergo, what have I done wrong?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the direction from enemy to player you can simplify the calculations a little.

### Find direction angle

```
var diffX = Player.x - Enemy.x,        // difference in position
    diffY = Player.y - Enemy.y,
    angle = Math.atan2(diffY, diffX);  // atan2 will give the angle in radians
```

Notice also difference for Y comes first for atan2 as canvas is oriented 0° pointing right.

### Velocity vector

Then calculate the velocity vector using angle and speed:

```
// calculate velocity vector
var speed = 8,
    vx = Math.cos(angle) * speed,   // angle x speed
    vy = Math.sin(angle) * speed;
```

You might want to consider using time as a factor if that is important. You can see **[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180765/modifier-inside-update-function-html5-canvas-game/22182522#22182522)** from a while back here for an example on this.

### Demo

Using these calculations you will be able to always "hit" the player with the projectile (reload demo to change enemy position to random y):

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    Player = {
      x: 470,
      y: 75
    },
    Enemy = {
      x: 100,
      y: Math.random() * 150  // reload demo to change y-position
    };

// calculate angle
var diffX = Player.x - Enemy.x,
    diffY = Player.y - Enemy.y,
    angle = Math.atan2(diffY, diffX);

// calculate velocity vector
var speed = 8,
    vx = Math.cos(angle) * speed,   // angle x speed
    vy = Math.sin(angle) * speed,
    x = Enemy.x,          // projectil start
    y = Enemy.y + 50;

// render
(function loop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 300);
  ctx.fillRect(Player.x, Player.y, 30, 100);
  ctx.fillRect(Enemy.x, Enemy.y, 30, 100);
  ctx.fillRect(x - 3, y -3, 6, 6);
  x += vx;
  y += vy;
  if (x < 500) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
})();
```

```html
<canvas width=500 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: fantastic! I need to adjust the axes in my instance but the above is mirroring the desired behaviour perfectly by 90 degrees (hey, at least that isn't hard to fix!)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is much simpler than that.

What should you do ?

1) compute the vector that leads from you enemy to the player. That will be the shooting direction.

2) normalize the vector : meaning you build a vector that has a length of 1, with the same direction.

3) multiply that vector by your speed : now you have a correct speed vector, with the right norm, aimed at the player.

Below some code to help you understand :

```
function spawnBullet(enemy, player) { 
  var shootVector = [];

  shootVector[0] = player[0] - enemy[0];
  shootVector[1] = player[1] - enemy[1];

  var shootVectorLength = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(shootVector[0], 2) + Math.pow(shootVector[1],2));

  shootVector[0]/=shootVectorLength;
  shootVector[1]/=shootVectorLength;

  shootVector[0]*=bulletSpeed;
  shootVector[1]*=bulletSpeed;

 // ... here return an object that has the enemy's coordinate
 // and shootVector as speed

 }
```

Then, since you don't use time in your computations (!! wrooong !! ;-) ) you will make the bullet move with the straightforward :

```
bullet[0] += bullet.speed[0];
bullet[1] += bullet.speed[1];
```

Now the issue with fixed-step is that your game will run, say, twice slower on a 30fps device than on a 60fps device. The solution is to compute how much time elapsed since the last refresh, let's call this time 'dt'. Using that time will lead you to an update like :

```
bullet[0] += dt * bullet.speed[0];
bullet[1] += dt * bullet.speed[1];
```

and now you'll be framerate-agnostic, your game will feel the same on any device.

Comment: Thanks for this, please would you elaborate on why I ought to use time in my computations?